# same value of width and min-width in css

Tags: html, css

I'm seeing this kind of code

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    width: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;
  }
```

And I couldn't reason about it. Is this an error or correct? If the width is larger it make sense but in this case where both values are the same I scratch my head to reason about it.

Comment: These lines doesn't work. One element like a tag or a class must be set. To your question: If the content of a block is smaller than 200px (small image 100x100px for example) then block width is 100px. But with min-width block width is 200px.

Comment: Meh.....without knowing the full context of who wrote it and why it's impossible to answer. It works but it is redundant in most circumstances.

Comment: it work but what's the point? @Paulie_D I don't think the context is important, I couldn't find the make-sense-context

Answer (score 0):

It is a Media query that is specifying the width properties min-width and width for screen sizes less than 300px.

What is puzzling is, as to which CSS (div?) element are you applying these width properties?

min-width and width pointing to the same value means that the width (usually of an element) cannot go below 200px when the screen size falls below 300px (per your media query) and the width can stay at 200px. You can also specify a max-width which can either be equal-to/greater-than 200px but less-than 300px.